# How to implement MutableSequence on custom class

Tags: python, pycharm, overloading, abc

I want to use a class like a list. I found out that inheriting and implementing `collections.abc.MutableSequence` makes the class list-like, but I don't know how to overload methods such as `__getitem__`, `__setitem__` for integer and slice seperately.

Pycharm generates code like below:

```py
class Test(collections.abc.MutableSequence):
    def insert(self, index: int, object: _T) -> None:
        pass

    @overload
    @abstractmethod
    def __getitem__(self, i: int) -> _T: ...

    @overload
    @abstractmethod
    def __getitem__(self, s: slice) -> MutableSequence[_T]: ...

    def __getitem__(self, i: int) -> _T:
        pass

    @overload
    @abstractmethod
    def __setitem__(self, i: int, o: _T) -> None: ...

    @overload
    @abstractmethod
    def __setitem__(self, s: slice, o: Iterable[_T]) -> None: ...

    def __setitem__(self, i: int, o: _T) -> None:
        pass

    @overload
    @abstractmethod
    def __delitem__(self, i: int) -> None: ...

    @overload
    @abstractmethod
    def __delitem__(self, i: slice) -> None: ...

    def __delitem__(self, i: int) -> None:
        pass

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        pass
```

I know Python does not support overloading but there are several ways to do

but I just want to follow the flow of `Pycharm`.

so I want to utilise the `@overload` decorator, but I can't understand how to use it.

Can anyone make an easy example? I would also be very grateful for just some references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `collections.UserList` is a [good example](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/208a7e957b812ad3b3733791845447677a704f3e/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L1174) of how to properly implement the `collections.abc.MutableSequence` API.
2. Check out this [YouTube talk](https://youtu.be/S_ipdVNSFlo) by Raymond Hettinger on Python's Abstract Base Classes and how to use them.
3. The `typing.overload` decorator is irrelevant to the runtime implementation of a function. Its sole purpose is to aid static type-checking. Good blog on how/when to use it [here](https://adamj.eu/tech/2021/05/29/python-type-hints-how-to-use-overload/).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. now I understand the @overload just for type hint and I should use conditional statement using isinstance function